# inner join two tables on two fields - matching on month and year for the date field oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables where the date field is populated with monthly data.  One of the date fields uses the start of the month and one uses the end of the month.  I am using an INNER JOIN using two fields, but I can't get the formatting of the dates to work:

```
SELECT * FROM crd_own.ml_corp_index_data_monthly  tb1
INNER JOIN pm_own.esg_credit_factors tb2 
ON tb1.TICKER = tb2.ISSUER_TICKER
AND to_date('tbl.DATADATE', 'yyyy/mm') =to_date('tb2.AS_OF_DATE', 'yyyy/mm')
```

Comment: remove the apostrophe's around the `'tbl.datadate'` and `'tb2.as_ofdate'`  You're telling ORACLE  to convert the string to a date which its going to fail.  you want the column names so the system will use the values in the row.  Also give some sample data as I'm not sure what your date fields for the two columns looks like and if it's really a date field or a varchar2?  so is the actual format of the date in both columns 2018/01?

Comment: Are the columns `tb1.datadate` and `tb2.as_of_date` of `date` data type, or are they strings? If they are dates already, don't use `TO_DATE()` on them! Actually you shouldn't use `TO_CHAR()` either, but use `TRUNC(... , 'mm')` instead, on the date that is end-of-month, to compare it to the beginning-of-month.

Comment: DATADATE is DATE data type and so is AS_OF_DATE

Comment: SELECT * FROM crd_own.ml_corp_index_data_monthly  tb1
    INNER JOIN pm_own.esg_credit_factors tb2 
    ON tb1.TICKER = tb2.ISSUER_TICKER
    AND TRUNC(tbl.DATADATE, 'mm') =tb2.AS_OF_DATE

Comment: I tried the changes above but I'm doing something wrong as I get an error

Comment: ORA-00904: "TBL"."DATADATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Oracle, you can `trunc` both dates to month and then compare them. Please not that, as commented by @xQbert, you don't want to enclose dates in quotes because that prevents Oracle from interpretating dates properly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    crd_own.ml_corp_index_data_monthly  tb1
    INNER JOIN pm_own.esg_credit_factors tb2 
        ON tb1.TICKER = tb2.ISSUER_TICKER
        AND trunc(tb1.DATADATE, 'month') = trunc(tb2.AS_OF_DATE, 'month')
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM crd_own.ml_corp_index_data_monthly  tb1
INNER JOIN pm_own.esg_credit_factors tb2 
ON tb1.TICKER = tb2.ISSUER_TICKER
AND trunc(tb2.AS_OF_DATE, 'month') = trunc(tbl.DATADATE, 'month')

Comment: Hi GMB, thanks! I used the above and got the error: ORA-00904: "TBL"."DATADATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 43

Comment: last line `trunc(tbl.DATADATE, 'month')` should be  `trunc(tb1.DATADATE, 'month') 
 tbl vs tb1 `

Comment: Thanks!!  I've been staring at this for hours!

Comment: @XQbert : thanks ! That was actually a typo in the OP, that I did not pay attention to. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: My two are faulty ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone....  this works:

```
SELECT * FROM crd_own.ml_corp_index_data_monthly  tb1
INNER JOIN pm_own.esg_credit_factors tb2 
ON tb1.TICKER = tb2.ISSUER_TICKER
AND trunc(DATADATE, 'month') = trunc(tb2.AS_OF_DATE, 'month')
```

Comment: Last line `AND trunc(tb1.DATADATE, 'month') = trunc(tb2.AS_OF_DATE, 'month')` the reason it failed earlier was becuase `tbl` vs `tb1` ONE vs letter L.  the 1st table was aliased tb1 not tbl.

Comment: You said one of them is already the start of the month. You should enter that one as-is in the equality check; you don't need TRUNC(..., 'month') on it. That way, if that column is indexed, the query will work a lot faster (and even if it isn't, it will work somewhat faster, since you have one less function call per row).

Comment: Thanks again everyone!